# Trying to come up with solution using recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I know there are multiple ways to find out if a word is palindromic, like using the reverse function of StringBuilder or even the reverse function of Collections, but in an attempt to learn recursion, I wrote it this way. I even had it working iteratively.

I kind of added return true in my embedded else statement, but I'm really not sure what to do, because when I run this in debug mode, it returns false, then invokes checkPalindrome again, which I don't understand why, because it should return and terminate, no? I would really appreciate an explanation of what I'm doing wrong and how to get it working this way.

```
public static boolean checkPalindrome(Deque deq) {
    if(deq.pollFirst() != deq.pollLast()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if(deq.size() == 1 || deq.size() == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            checkPalindrome(deq);
            return true // TODO ?? figure out What to put here ??
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's that you are not returning anything when you call yourself. The inner else statement should read this:

```
else {
    return checkPalindrome(deq);
}
```

---

You have a followup question in the comments below that leads me to want to explain how recursive methods work, but in essence, they all follow the following pseudo-code:

```
public boolean someMethod(T[] someArrayOrList) {
    // return true  -OR-
    // return false -OR-
    // call yourself and return whatever that call returns
}
```

No matter what, when you call the method it will return SOMETHING... Either it will return something itself, or it will return whatever some other call of itself will return. In a way it is AND'ing all the responses, but in reality TRUE is only generated once.

Comment: _Falls to knees and screams_ **noooo**

I was worried that might be the answer... so confused as to why? Does it AND over each instance?

Comment: You had the concept, and your failure is a common one when learning how to build recursive methods.

Comment: So it works the way you suggested, however I'm super confused as to why, it returns false, then executes next statement or executes return true;, then goes to the next statement, can you clear that up for me? Or is it just getting the previous values of the return? How does it to know to end?

Is it saying first instance, TRUE, next TRUE, Last one FALSE, so it's saying return TRUE && TRUE && FALSE?

Comment: Ohh great, makes sense now. Thank you for the explanation.